# Python Blender math.trunc()

Tags: python, blender

iam trying to use the math.trunc in Blender 2.49b Python

but iam getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'trunc'
```

i also imported math

its on line

```
uv[i][0] = trunc(uv[i][0] * 100000) / 100000
```

i also tryied it via the int, like

```
uv[i][0] = int(uv[i][0] * 100000) / 100000
```

which gives me an error

> TypeError: 'float' object is
>   unsubscriptable

so how should i trunc the value:(

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error seems to imply that `uv` in your code is a float object and you are trying to subscript it `uv[i]`. Try to `math.trunc(uv)` and see. Also you can check if trunc is available by doing `hasattr(math,'trunc')`

Comment: hasattr(math,'trunc') returns false and only trunc(...) gives error NameError: global name 'trunc' is not defined

Comment: Peter that means that you math library which blender is using or invoking the python installed in your system does not have `trunc`. Just use `round(number,1)` for your purposes which rounds off the number to the number of decimal places you specify in the second argument.

Comment: yes, but round is not exactly the same as trunc... how to come, that it doesnt have such a basic function like trunc?

Comment: i found a way by using int, but f.uv[i][0] = int(f.uv[i][0] * 100000) / 100000 turns 0.5 into 0 :(

Comment: `math.trunc` is available from python2.6 only and perhaps your system's default python is lesser than that and blender is using that. I don't use blender so I don't know the specific details, but you can try upgrading to Python2.6 and reinstalling blender.

Comment: OTOH, you can achieve the `trunc` effect by `str` your float and then slicing them.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend what verson of Python is used by Blender (I imagine that would be Python 2.5).

Try this in Blender:

```
import math
help(math)
```

This will crash Blender, but you will be able to see the math to the library under **FILE** and you should be able to scroll down to see if the trunc function is available in the version of Python used by Blender. It might be not present, which would explain the error.